# (Singular) metric associated to the higher cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a smooth complex variety and $L$ is a line bundle with a metric $h_L$, then a section $s \in H^0(X, L)$ gives another metric $\tilde h_L:= e^{-\phi}h_L$ where $\phi=\log \|s\|^2_{h_L}$.

If $u \in H^q(X,L)$ is a section (or just $u\in H^q(X,K_X)$), is there a way to construct a metric on $L$ with some relation to $u$?

Comment: If an $n-q$ dimensional cohomology class could cupped with that class, giving a class in $H^n$, and if that space comes equipped with a norm, you're in business.